# Maven give me error with spring 4.0.3 only

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I have problem with my spring-project.When i start add depenency to my pom.xml i notice i can't add depenency like spring-tx or spring-orm in version 4.0.3.RELEASE, its work with all another version i test - 4.0.0.RELEASE - 4.0.5.RELEASE(without 0.3 of course).

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-
v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dinor913.example</groupId>
<artifactId>ExampleProjectHibernate</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ExampleProjectHibernate Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Eclipse give me error

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for   
org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to   
transfer org.springframework:spring-tx:pom:4.0.3.RELEASE from 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not
be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-tx:pom:4.0.3.RELEASE 
from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-
4.0.3.RELEASE.pom
```

I checked url 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.pom   and i see xml there so why i get error null to(<- this url)?

I am only curious why i get this error with spring 4.0.3.RELEASE in my project i change on working version

Comment: have you tried to run the maven command outside eclipse, and with debug messages on (`-X`)? what does it say?

Comment: I can build successful pom.xml outside eclipse but when i run eclipse i still have error.

Comment: so this is eclipse problem only. Could you add that to the question?

Comment: Eclipse has a strong capacity to cache wrong data ... I once had to de-install, re-install Eclipse to have it functional again.